# Win32 Console -- Backspace to Last Line

Tags: winapi, console, console-application

I'm writing a command interpreter like BASH, and a `\` followed by a newline implies a continuation of the input stream; how can I implement that in Win32?

If I use the console mode with `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT`, then the user can't press *backspace* in order to go back to the previous line; Windows prevents him from doing so. But if I don't set `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT`, then I have to manually reposition the cursor, which is rather tedious given that (1) the user might have redirected the input stream, and that (2) it might be prone to race conditions, and I'd rather have Windows do it if I can.

Any way to have my newline and eat it too?

---

**Edit:**

If this would require undocumented CSRSS port requests, then I'm still interested!

Comment: This can probably be done by using the "Unicode" version of `ReadConsole` by setting  `nInitialChars` in the `pInputControl` parameter.

Comment: @Amigable: Yeah I was afraid of that...
@John: Hm... I tried passing in a value for `pInputControl` to `ReadConsoleW` both with and without `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` mode, and I still didn't see any difference... :\

Comment: Why is it prone to race conditions to position the cursor yourself? I ask because I would go for that route if I were you. It gives the most control, but it should in some sense be easier in the Windows world, since you don't have to take into account a zillion different terminals.

Comment: @Amigable: Because there's the issue of what happens if something is written to the stream while I'm moving back the cursor? Then I'll overwrite something. There's also the issue of making the history thing work with the up/down keys... it's just too tedious to do 100% correctly.

Comment: Hm, I don't know the Windows terms, but you WOULD have to use "uncooked" mode echo off. Yes, very tedious indeed. Maybe you could use another terminal than the standard windows one?  Something like putty or some natively ported version of rxvt or something. Dunno, just an idea...  good luck with your pursuit!

Comment: @Amigable: Well the entire point of my program was to use the standard Windows terminal, since it integrates well with the rest of the system. :) Thanks though!

Comment: Hm, an EVIL way would be to use DirectX to snoop on input!  :-D

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56#c12  Maybe interesting info.

Comment: @Amigable: Yeah, that's definitely interesting info, thanks for sharing the link! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want this to run in a window, like command prompt does by default, rather than full screen, you could create a GUI application with a large textbox. Users would type into the textbox, and you could parse whatever was entered, and output to the same box (effectively emulated the Win32 Console).

This way whatever rules you want to set for how the console behaves is completely up to you.

I might be mistaken is saying this, but I believe that the Win32 Console from XP onward works exactly like this, and it just listens for output on stdout; there shouldn't be any reason you can't do the same.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, like I mentioned in a comment on my post, `the entire point of my program was to use the standard Windows terminal, since it integrates well with the rest of the system` in many ways, and making a text box wouldn't be equivalent to that because it wouldn't be a "native" console (i.e. it wouldn't be recognized by the OS as a console app), and I'm really not looking for a way to fool the user and the OS into thinking something that's not true. :(

Comment: Then look into how console-based text editors work, as this is essentially how you'll need to accept commands. You'll have to buffer the command, and manipulate the cursor position yourself when you need to trace back a line.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid that might be the answer... thanks for the help.